# How to handle TFS DLLs with two different versions of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

So I'm working on a program that interacts with TFS via the API, I am running things like check in check out, get workspace etc.

We recently updated to Visual studio 2015, this is where the problem happens. I had to re-add my references to the DLL's from here. Now the program works on my machine but not on any elses who use the 2013 version of Visual Studio.

If I grab the DLL's from the older version of Visual Studio, it works on their machines but not mine.

I can't seem to find a way to be able to get this to work on both machines.

Any ideas?

It's specifically failing on the get workspace portion of the code.

```
 workspace = versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(path);
```

It always returns the no items mapped exception.

any method using versioncontrolserver always returns there is no mapping error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each visual studio SDK version uses a server registry that is unique to the Assembly version of the SDK. Hence server registrations in VS2013 are not immediately visible in VS2015 and calls using the v14 SDK won't see a mapping made in using the V12 SDK. This is what you're running into.

### Have TFS populate the server data

By providing the project collection uri upon connecting, the server will be able to provide the correct workspace mappings and everything will work.

If you want your utility to detect the settings without first connecting to the server you'll need to detect this condition and them you can [pop-up the server registration UI by calling the TeamProjectPicker to register the connection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/team_foundation/2010/04/20/using-the-teamprojectpicker-api-in-tfs-2010/).

If you're able to connect to the remote server, but the local workspaces are not yet brought over, call the [`Workstation.UpdateWorkspaceInfoCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139711(v=vs.120).aspx) method to have it populate the data for your version of the SDK.

An alternate way to duplicate the TFS server connection information is to  duplicate the corresponding registry keys under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{VERSION}\TeamFoundation\Instances
```

to the `14.0` tree before establishing a connection to the server with your version of the API. You only need to register the server once for the settings to be replicated over upon connecting.

### Build a version specific edition of your utility

Or you can indeed provide a version that is specifically built for one version of the SDK. [One way of handling this can be found in this open source project](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/blob/master/References/TfsReferences.target). It uses the Project Configuration to conditionally load one set of references or another. This way you can switch between the version to build using the Solution Configuration dropdown in Visual Studio:

```
 <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(TfsVersion)' == '12.0'">
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
    </When>
    <When Condition="'$(TfsVersion)' == '14.0' Or '$(TfsVersion)' == '14.1'">
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </Reference>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

You can optionally provide a `<HintPath>` to the specific file location of the assembly as well.

In the link mentioned above the location of these files is detected automatically by looking up the Visual studio installation location from the registry (for additional bonus points).

There are some breaking changes between versions of the TFS SDK. So you may need to use Compiler Constants to select which code to use. The referenced example does this as follows:

```
 <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(TfsVersion)' == '14.0' or '$(TfsVersion)' == '14.1'">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <DefineConstants Condition="'$(TfsVersion)' == '14.0'">$(DefineConstants);TFS2015</DefineConstants>
            <DefineConstants Condition="'$(TfsVersion)' == '14.1'">$(DefineConstants);TFS2015u1;TFS2015</DefineConstants>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition="'$(TfsVersion)' == '14.0' or '$(TfsVersion)' == '14.1'">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <DefineConstants Condition="'$(TfsVersion)' == '12.0'">$(DefineConstants);TFS2013</DefineConstants>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

In the code you [can then do the following](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/blob/master/Aggregator.Core/Facade/RequestContextWrapper.cs):

```
#if TFS2015 || TFS2015u1
using ILocationService = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Server.ILocationService;
#elif TFS2013
using ILocationService = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationLocationService;
#endif
```

To instuct the compiler to use specific parts of your code for specific SDK versions.

It's not pretty, but then again backwards and forwards compatibility is hard.

Comment: I do connect to the uri at the beginning and it returns a version control server object with the correct information, it's just when I hit the version control server methods they can't see the workspace. If I use query workspace I can see all the workspaces and I can set the workspace from there but it always errors out on the version control server methods with nonworking gofolder mapping.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. Been racking my head over this for a week now

Comment: Workstation.UpdateWorkspaceInfoCache was the one that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) for TFS API to your project and then use it as references. This does not rely on the VS version, just need to restore the nuget packages before build the project on other machines.

Comment: If I install the nuget package it will work locally on my machine, but when I try the program on the remote machine it throws an error "There are no working map folders for ***"

If I simply switch the dll's to V12 it works though.